# sound problems in safari and firefox (playing mp3 on mouseenter, click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, safari

this code is working perfect in chrome but the sound isn´t playing in firefox and safari – i was tying some other ways to make it work but there was no solution with combining a single sound on mouseenter ond do the loop on click. – does someone know a solution

---

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
      var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
      audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'audio/01T.wav');
      audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay:false', 'autoplay');

      $.get();
      audioElement.addEventListener("load", function () {
          audioElement.play();
      }, false);

      $('.letter1').mouseenter(function () { 
        $(this).addClass('shake shake-constant').stop().delay(3000).queue(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('shake shake-constant');
          });
          audioElement.play();
      });


      var audioElementb = document.createElement('audio');
      audioElementb.setAttribute('src', 'audio/01T.wav');
      audioElementb.setAttribute('autoplay:false', 'autoplay');
      audioElementb.loop=true;

      $.get();
      audioElementb.addEventListener("load", function () {
          audioElementb.play();
      }, false);

      $('.letter1').on('click', function(){
         $( this ).toggleClass( "serif shake2 shake-constant2" );


      if (audioElementb.paused) {
       audioElementb.play();
      } else {
       audioElementb.pause();
        }
      });
```

});

Comment: Have you tried another format ? maybe .wav is not supported in these browsers ? I don't know your goal, but you could also look for a crossbrowsers audio plugin. I tried buzzjs once, it worked really good, but I don't know if it's still updated

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. i´ll try this. my main problem was that i hadnt had any idea where i´ve to search for the problem.